# how to define for in rweka- InfoGainAttributeEval

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree, rweka

is there anybody can tell me how to define the formula in the rweka?

A<- InfoGainAttributeEval(formula ~ . , data = TrainDataLSVT,na.action=NULL )

there are 310 features in the TrainDataLSVT.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide your data, I will illustrate with the built-in iris data (see `?iris`).   For this data, the goal is to predict the Species as a function of the other variables. You can express that as a formula for `InfoGainAttributeEval` like this:

```
InfoGainAttributeEval(Species ~ ., data=iris)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   0.6982615    0.3855963    1.4180030    1.3784027
```

The values returned are the scores for each variable. The key part is the formula `Species ~ .` You should read this as "Species as a function of all other variables". Details on how to write a formula are available on the help page `?formula`.